# gvis.editor shrinks chartsize when applied

Tags: r, charts, size, ggvis, shrink

I have tried to find an answer to the problem here at stackoverflow, r-bloggers and all the other relevant forums but without any luck.
I turn to you in the hope of finding a person who has experienced and solved a similar problem.

I am using the Googlevis package to create presentations in R-studio. Particularly the gvis.editor I find very useful since different people prefer different ways of illustration. So far so good. Although, the editor works as it should it shrinks the original size of the chart and makes it difficult to see. I have demonstrated the issue below

Original size chart

[image]

Shrinked chart (after gvis.editor applied)

[image]

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: hard to say exactly without seeing the code -- it looks as if the chart is the same size as when it was open in the editor -- assuming there are no hard-coded sizes, you could try re-drawing the chart, once it is back on the page...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response :)

Comment: The chart gets smaller, each time I use the gvis.editor, which I have called "Customize". Re-drawing it doesn't make any change.